# Weird Ocean Lighting in Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Thank you for reading this. I'm making a ocean scene in blender, it looks perfectly find in the actual layout tab, but when I render it the ocean lighting just turns white. I've attached a screenshot, Thanks :D

Comment: Hello, I can't see the screenshot, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: As @moonboots says you haven't added a screenshot. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.